# How to place quotes around a SQL parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I'm trying to make a full-text search stored procedure. It stores the search keyword/term in a parameter that is passed to it from a web form.

Single word search work fine, but when I search for a phrase such as "Xbox One" then it fails. I know that I need to surround the phrase in quotes for it to work but because its parametrized I don't know how to achieve it.

Here is how my code looks:

```
    DECLARE @SearchTerm nvarchar(1000)
    SELECT
      ProductName
    FROM
      dbo.Products p1
    WHERE
      CONTAINS((p1.ProductName), @SearchTerm)
```

I need to place the `@SearchTerm` parameter like this: `N' "@SearchTerm" '` but that obviously doesn't work as is.

How can I allow for CONTAINS phrase searches that have spaces in the strings when I am using a parameter to hold the SearchTerm?

Comment: Pretty sure that you can just concatenate them.  `N' "' + @SearchTerm + '" '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you attempted:

```
DECLARE @SearchTerm nvarchar(1000)
SET @SearchTerm = N'"' + @SearchTerm + N'"'
SELECT
  ProductName
FROM
  dbo.Products p1
WHERE
  CONTAINS((p1.ProductName), @SearchTerm)
```